# Where can this FAQ be found on an official site?

Tags: crayon-rail-games

On [this site](http://www.railgamefans.com/ebp/mayfairebfaq.htm), there is a list of crayon rail games FAQ and accompanying answers, presumably from Mayfair games.  I don't want to doubt the authenticity of that list.  Rather, I'd like confirmation that the information given in there *really is from Mayfair Games*.  Ideally, I'd like an FAQ from an official source, but confirmation that this is really from Mayfair would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any information about why the FAQ is being hosted at the fan site, and not at Mayfair Games itself, but there are several circumstantial pieces of evidence.

1. Mayfair Games [don't have a FAQ for Empire Builder](http://mayfairgames.com/faq.php?game=105).
2. Mayfair Games links to the fan site (implying endorsement) from their [official Empire Builder page](http://mayfairgames.com/game.php?id=105&stock=MFG4500&name=Empire%20Builder).
3. That site is also the developer of the official computer version (i.e. licensed from Mayfair Games).
4. The resources for the game are comprehensive. It's unlikely they would make the FAQ up and then claim it was from the publisher.
5. There is [another FAQ](http://www.railgamefans.com/ebp/ebfaq.htm) on the same site which indicates it is the set of rules by which the largest tournaments are played. That argues that this site is indeed the keeper of the de-facto most "official" FAQ.

For completeness, I did do some digging in the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) for a FAQ from 2008 hosted at Mayfair Games, but found nothing.

Interesting question. The linked FAQs look detailed and helpful. Now I'm curious as to why you *require* proof of provenance.

Comment: I guess I don't _require_ it, I just really wanted confirmation, which you helped provide.  In particular, the way I play involves only being able to build out of a major city for free ONCE, so that is potentially a big change.

Comment: The 1988 rules clearly say: "A player may not build more than two track sections from a major city mileposts during one turn."   So your play is wrong to start with.